# For email client programs, does having the reading pane on indicate the email has been read

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, virus, spam-prevention

When the reading pane is on and messages can be viewed without opening them, is this the equivalent of reading an email?  I mostly use Microsoft Outlook 2013 but I am looking for a general answer for email clients because I also use Mozilla Thunderbird.  The situation I am trying to understand is when I receive an email that may be spam, how can I avoid reading the email and triggering a response by my email program to the sender.  I'd like to know if having the reading pane on is a way of reading the email without indicating that I have read it.

Comment: Are you auto responding to all read emails or something so the indicator to all your read email senders in your response would imply you read the email and responded I suppose unless you put something in that response stating this is an auto response and does not mean I've read this email. There are options in Outlook to say something about reading the message in the reading pane, DO NOT tag this email as READ.  If you  have some rule to auto-respond to only READ emails enabling that option would fix your issue.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do still though or what you've configured.

Comment: Disable the reading preview feature within the client itself.  The behavior of the preview pane, and if this is enough to trigger any tracking within the email itself, is entirely dependent on the client itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I avoid reading the email and triggering a response by my email program to the sender

Just reading an email won't signal back to the sender.

An exception to this is when images in the email reference external images. The sender can use that to track if you've read it by checking the image requests on the image server.

This is why Outlook disables automatic image showing by default.

Another exception is if you have auto-respond to Read Requests configured in your email client, but that (along with any other auto-responder setup) is something you'd have to setup on purpose.

Comment: It seems marketing companies such as Contact Contact have additional means of determining when an email has been read.